# Capture rendered HTML for use in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I have some rendered HTML text within some div's, etc., and I would like to able to capture whatever was rendered into a WebGL texture. Is this possible without pre-rendering? I ask because different browsers render slightly differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ which can reconstruct what is rendered by visiting the DOM and writing to a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Google maze (chrome.com/maze) also uses some rendering of the HTML, but becauseit can be cross-domain and because of its response time my guess is they used some kind of snapshoting of pages on some server and then just retrieving the final result.

Hope this helps.